# Compare two batch records in spark stream

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Currently I'm working on Spark Streaming and data volume will be huge and I have the following scenario.

Every 2 mins,Streamed data will be processed. During some transformations, I will need to validate against the data which may come in next batch (i.e) after 2 mins. In such cases , I need to hold these particular data on in-memory or Disk plus in-memory combo so that these data will be compared in next batch/after 2 mins .
 Either Accumulator nor broadcast variables won't be help in my case.In this case what would be the best approach?

Comment: U could try windowing and state?

Comment: I'm not using dataframes. still I can make you of it ?

Comment: Dont think u need to use dataframes to do windowing, you could do that on the DStream itself

Comment: okay.Thanks for answering. Let me check with tat.